# OrderBy with matched words from a search feature

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have search feature that passes search terms to my query and i filter my query via those search terms but i'm very unsure on how to order those results via the matched words.

```
string[] seperator = { " " };
string[] filteredSearchTerms = searchTerm.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);

List<Ticket> tickets = (from t in entities.tbl_Ticket
                                where
                                 t.tbl_Campaign.CampaignName == user.campaignName &
                                 filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => t.Description.Contains(v))
                                select new Ticket
                                {
                                    dateAdded = (DateTime)t.DateAdded,
                                    description = t.Description,
                                    name = t.Name,
                                    ticketID = t.TicketID,
                                    statusID = (int)t.StatusID,
                                    SearchTerms = filteredSearchTerms.ToList()
                                }).AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(obj => filteredSearchTerms.Any(v => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(obj.description, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", v))))
                                .Take(10).ToList();
```

So if the first result has all the words in its description then that should appear at the top of the list. I am not to sure if it's possible in my current context. Ive tried OrderByDescending with a similar Where extension as the filter.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Regards,

Tez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OrderByDescending(). An example for your scenario below.

```
string[] searchTerms = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };            
var descriptions = new List<string>(new string[] { "one string", "two string", "one two three string", "one two string", "no match" });
var filteredDescriptions = descriptions.Where(description => searchTerms.Count(searchTerm => description.Contains(searchTerm)) > 0);
var orderedDescriptions = filteredDescriptions.OrderByDescending(description => searchTerms.Count(searchTerm => description.Contains(searchTerm)));
```

I get the following result.

one two three string
one two string
one string
two string

Hope this helps.